# Using CBLOF for a highly imbalanced dataset - Value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, unsupervised-learning

I am using the unsupervised learning model, CBLOF, for training my dataset, which has the following class imbalance:

[image]

I am getting this error when trying to run my model over this dataset:

```
model_cblof = CBLOF(contamination = 0.05) 
train_test_models(model_cblof, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 2
      1 model_cblof = CBLOF(contamination = 0.05, n_clusters=1) 
----> 2 train_test_models(model_cblof, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

Cell In[22], line 28, in train_test_models(model, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
     25 accuracies = []
     27 #train model on data
---> 28 model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     30 #find accuracy score
     31 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\F21DL\lib\site-packages\pyod\models\cblof.py:194, in CBLOF.fit(self, X, y)
    189     warnings.warn("The chosen clustering for CBLOF forms {0} clusters"
    190                   "which is inconsistent with n_clusters ({1}).".
    191                   format(self.n_clusters_, self.n_clusters))
    193 self._set_cluster_centers(X, n_features)
--> 194 self._set_small_large_clusters(n_samples)
    196 self.decision_scores_ = self._decision_function(X,
    197                                                 self.cluster_labels_)
    199 self._process_decision_scores()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\F21DL\lib\site-packages\pyod\models\cblof.py:292, in CBLOF._set_small_large_clusters(self, n_samples)
    290     self._clustering_threshold = beta_list[0]
    291 else:
--> 292     raise ValueError("Could not form valid cluster separation. Please "
    293                      "change n_clusters or change clustering method")
    295 self.small_cluster_labels_ = sorted_cluster_indices[
    296                              self._clustering_threshold:]
    297 self.large_cluster_labels_ = sorted_cluster_indices[
    298                              0:self._clustering_threshold]

ValueError: Could not form valid cluster separation. Please change n_clusters or change clustering method
```

While I did change the number of clusters, did normalisation and so on, nothing changed and the error persists. Do I need to change something in my code, or does CBLOF just doesn't work well on this particular dataset?

Note: This is a fraud detection model, with only 2 classes.